# Baker Ebook Framework: How can I properly package "book" folder as .hpub format?

Tags: ios, frameworks

Baker Ebook Framework relies on the **hpub** format for books. I'm trying to create a book link target an external book followed [their instruction](https://github.com/Simbul/baker/wiki/Managing-links-and-urls) trying both **.hpub** (just simply rename the book folder to book.hpub) and **.zip** format:

```
<a href="book://www.mysite.com/books/new-book.zip">Link to new book.zip</a>

<a href="book://www.mysite.com/books/new-book.hpub">Link to new book.hpub</a>
```

The result is when I clicked the link, the book package is downloaded and extracted but cannot open and said that **"Sorry, that book had no pages."**

I wonder that the problem is my book package.

Please suggest me the proper way to package my book as **.hpub** or other formats that can be opened by Baker Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure that the book.json file contains a "contents" element with the paths to your pages.  This file should be in the root of your book's zip file.

i.e. You have to zip the contents of your book directory and not the book directory itself.  If there is a directory in the root of your zip file, with all of your source files in that, then there's your problem.

Note: once zipped, as long as your file doesn't have a html extension it will be treated as a zip file, so you can use .hpub or .zip